# How to add a specific pdf page as an image in org-mode, and correctly export it?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I am working in a file `document.org`, and I have an embedded image, the second page of a file `images.pdf`.

The org-file shows this correctly (with the code shown below). However, upon exporting it to tex (let's say `document.tex`), the tex does not indicate that `\includegraphics{}` should use the second page.

```
#+attr_org: :width 80% :page 2
#+attr_latex: :width 0.95\textwidth
#+caption: My Caption
[[./images.pdf]]
```

This shows (in the buffer) the second page of `images.pdf`. But if I export the org file to tex or pdf, the resulting tex has:

```tex
...
\usepackage{graphicx}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.95\textwidth]{./images.pdf}
\caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}
...
\end{document}
```

Which leads to a pdf showing the first page of `images.pdf`. A natural thing to try was changing the `#+attr_latex...` line for

```
#+attr_latex: :width 0.95\textwidth :page 2
```

But it does nothing. How can I achieve this without cutting `images.pdf` into many individual files?

#### Workaround

I was pointed out that `ox-latex` does know about pages (to export), but the way you tell it about pages is not in `#+attr_org`, which in my opinion is weird...

```
#+attr_org: :width 80% :page 2
#+attr_latex: :width 0.95\textwidth
#+caption: My Caption
[[./images.pdf::2]]
```

Note that the only difference is the `::2` at the end of the filename. The odd thing is that this is telling `ox-latex` to *"export using the second page of images.pdf"*, but `#+attr_org` is the one saying *"show me here the second page of images.pdf"*.

So I have to manually keep `:page 2` and `::2` synchronized.

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/pdflatex-includegraphics-and-multi-page-pdf-files) might help.

Comment: I am indeed using graphicx, and if I modify the tex file, to add the `, page=2`, it works well. But I cannot get the page number argument by just exporting from org.

Comment: If worse comes to worst, you can use a [filter](https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) to modify the TeX output. But it may be possible to coerce the exporter to do it - I am looking into that, but I don't know how yet.

Comment: Until this works, could put the entire `\includegraphics` TeX source in a `LATEX` block?

Comment: hey, thanks. That is certainly an option. However, I found out that there is an easier workaround. I am editing my question right now. Still not ideal (because you need to keep both numbers manually synchronized), but it is not much overhead.